# What activation function is recommended in a neural network when I have a regression task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I would like to estimate a project budget based on several project data, and I also have historical data in the same data structure. I would like to do it with neural networks, however I am not sure what type of activation function I should use. I will have one output neuron which is supposed to tell me how much budget I should expect for my given input.

Comment: ReLU is a safe bet normally.

Comment: Leaky ReLU is an interesting alternative as well. When you enter into the zero regime of ReLU, you are stuck there. This may be sometimes an undesired behavior. Leaky ReLUs don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you'll want to stay away from sigmoidal activation functions when your output isn't supposed to follow some probability distribution. In these cases, when dealing with regression, I typically use some kind of linear unit.

So as erip suggested you could try ReLU. More generally there are a few linear units to choose from (discussed in more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function)), including PReLU and ELU. The best advice I can give is to train a few times, trying different linear units and changing their parameters, and see what works best for you model.